# Make router access Internet through network machine with dongle

Tags: networking, router, internet, 3g, dongle

I have an ASUS RTN66U running Tomato firmware.

I have temporary (a month or so) Internet access via a Huawei E3131 3G USB dongle. I am posting this question using said Internet access.

I would like other machines on my network to be able to access the Internet in the usual fashion. That is, through my ASUS router.

My initial thought was to plug the dongle into the router and configure it to connect. However, it seems tomato does not support my dongle because I get a message to that effect in the log.

So my next thought was to "point" my router at my Windows machine which has the dongle plugged into it. Thus, any machine connecting to the router would then route through my Windows machine to the Internet.

The problem is, I have no idea how to set this up (or whether it's even possible). Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take your router out of the equation altogether and configure ICS (Internet Connection Sharing) on the machine with the 3g connection. There is plenty of documentation out there detailing the process. If you do not own a switch or a hub you can essentially turn your router into one by enabling bridge mode and/or disabling the routing features. (DHCP will need to be turned OFF.)

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but I don't believe I can use ICS. That's because one of the machines I need to connect with is a locked-down work machine. I then need to use VPN and a corporate proxy, so it needs to be transparent to that machine. ICS requires that I jump through some hoops on client machines that I can't jump through. That's why I would like this to occur via the router, which my work machine can connect to.

Answer (score 0):

On your windows machine simply create a network bridge between the usb modem and your ethernet port under the network connections menu, then connect your ethernet port to the internet/input side of a router (i am using an old belkin 54g router for this and also use an e3131 like yourself) your router should now broad cast the bridged internet connection to any machine you like.

The drawback with this is that the host machine needs to be powered on to share the internet connection, you can still connect to your wireless router from the host machine to transfer/share files etc across the network as you would before it will just just show that you are connected to multiple networks.

None of the machines connected to my router can tell that it is a shared internet connection, I can even access the 3g modem directly from any of the other pc's to disconnect/reconnect and monitor data usage etc just by typing 192.168.1.1 into the browser (huawei e3131 has no desktop dashboard to access connection interface only browser interface)